# Decide if there exists a holomorphic function $f$ in $B(0,1)$ : $f(\dfrac{1}{n})=\dfrac{1}{3-2n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine if there exists a holomorphic function in $B(0,1)$ such that $$f(\dfrac{1}{n})=\dfrac{1}{3-2n}, \space \forall \space n \in \mathbb N_{>1} $$

I've tried to define a function $h(z)=f(z)-\dfrac{z}{3z-2}$ in $B(0,\frac{2}{3})$. This function is holomorphic on that region and for the sequence $\{\dfrac{1}{n}\} \subset B(0,\frac{2}{3})$, $n>1$, we have $$h(\dfrac{1}{n})=f(\dfrac{1}{n})-\dfrac{1}{3-2n}=0$$

Since $\dfrac{1}{n} \to 0 \in B(0,\frac{2}{3})$, then $h$ is identically zero in $B(0,\frac{2}{3})$, which means $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{3z-2}$ for all $z \in B(0,\dfrac{2}{3})$

I've realized up to now I haven't proved or disproved the original statement. I haven't arrived to any absurd conclusion but I don't know what else to do. I would appreciate suggestions, or maybe there is an absurd but I still haven't noticed.

Comment: Note that $f(z)=\frac{1}{3-2z}$ satisfies $f(1/n)=\frac{n}{3n-2}\ne \frac{1}{3-2n}.$

Comment: It was a typo, I've corrected it.

Comment: "I haven't arrived to any absurd conclusion" Hmmm... I think you have. You showed that every solution on B(0,1) must take a specific form on B(0,2/3). Now every holomorphic function on B(0,1) is bounded on B(0,2/3) and your restricted function is not, hence...

Comment: Oops, Liouville's theorem... thanks!

Comment: @Did $|\dfrac{z}{3z-2}|<\dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{1}{|3z-2|}$, how can I show that $\dfrac{1}{|3z-2|}$ is bounded? I've tried using $||3z|-|2||<|3z-2|$ but I couldn't arrive to anything.

Comment: It is NOT bounded (since it explodes at z=2/3), this is the point of the proof.

Comment: And I've said Liouville's theorem but that only works for entire functions so, let me see if now I get what you mean: on $\overline{B(0,\dfrac{2}{3})}$ $f$ must be bounded because is a continuous function on a compact set, but $f$ is not bounded since $|f(z)| \to \infty$ when $z \to \dfrac{2}{3}$   which is absurd.

Comment: Replace $\overline{B(0,1)}$ by $\overline{B(0,3/4)}$, say, and you are done.

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking that I've proved that $f=\dfrac{z}{3z-2}$ on $B(0,\dfrac{2}{3})$ but why would $f=\dfrac{z}{3z-2}$ on the closed ball? I can't use the identity theorem for a larger ball than $B(0,\dfrac{2}{3})$ since this function is not holomorphic for a radius greater than $\dfrac{2}{3}$ or the closed ball of radius $\dfrac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Let me repeat. You ASSUME there is a solution on B(0,1). Then you prove this solution must be unbounded on B(0,2/3). But every solution, being holomorphic on B(0,1), must be bounded on B(0,3/4). Contradiction. (Unrelated: Please use @.)